# Duvida na resolução de um exercício utilizando while ou for

Tags: c

Boa noite meus caros,
Minha duvida é referente a repetição (while e for).
Em um exercício eu quero imprimir os números de um a 10. Porem quero agrupa-los de 2 em 2, ou de 3 em 3 para seguir essa logica:

1. 123
2. 456
3. 789
4. ...

---

Muito obrigado pela atenção.
Att,

Comment: poderia [edit] seu post e adicionar o que ja tentou fazer até agora, assim fica mais fácil te ajudar :) Abraço

Comment: Não está claro o problema. Se você tentou alguma solução, poderia postar para facilitar

Comment: nao esta bem especifico sua pergunta, tem como postar o que voce ja fez para termos uma nocao do que precisa, e saber ate aonde chegou!

Answer (score 3):

Olá, sua dúvida não está tão clara, tente apresentar um pedaço do codigo que tem.

Segue um algoritmo que resolve a questão (de acordo com o que entendi da sua pergunta) agrupando de 2 em 2, e quando chega em 10 reinicia a contagem:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, aux = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
        printf("%d. ", i);
        for (j = aux; j <= (aux + 1); j++){
            printf("%d ", j);
        }
        aux = j;
        if(aux > 9) aux = 1;
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```